# Concise way of prefixing string if prefix is not empty

Tags: ruby

Is there a shorter way of doing the following?

```
foo = 
  config.include?(:bar) ?
    "#{bar}.baz" :
    "baz"
```

I'm looking for a readable one-liner that appends a variable, plus a delimiter, if the variable exists (assuming it's a string).

`config` is a Hash.

Comment: that looks short and readable to me

Comment: Write what (class) `config` is. Don't let the readers guess. And your title and the question do not seem to match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
foo = [bar, 'baz'].compact.join('.')
```

If `bar` is nil then `compact` will remove it from the array and delimiter won't be added.

Comment: that doesn't do the same thing. config.include? could have more meaning than a nil

Comment: Yes, I know. Probably I assumed too much.

Comment: In my situation, `bar` would always be `nil` if it is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = "#{"bar." if config.include?(:bar)}baz"
```